# How to block an ip address after several wrong login attempts

Tags: login, password, ip-address

I have an web application which needs the user to login.
On the server there is an php page who does this (it will check the user input against a mysql table).
If an user tries to login with a wrong password for several times I want to block his/her ip address.

**What is the best way to do that?**

I can make an new mysql table and store the blocked ip addresses there, but this is an query which has to be done every time to check if an ip address is blocked or not. If an ip address is blocked that is for an good reason and I want to spend as less resources as possible to block him. So, what is the best or fastest way to block an ip address. The server OS I use is Ubuntu. So I thought maybe there is some build in method within Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at fail2ban[1]. It is primarily designed to prevent brute force SSH breaking attempts, but there are many additional modules[2] that have been written that work great for WordPress and other WebApps.

[1]http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

[2]http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/use-fail2ban-to-blacklist-ip-addresses-and-alert-you-to-attacks/

Best, 
Lev

Comment: How does this compare to iptables with ipsets (which I found just a minute ago).

Comment: It *is* `iptables` with `ipsets` managed by an easy-to-use script. Using fail2ban would require you to write a plugin for it, so you might as well leave fail2ban out of it altogether.

Comment: I believe this would fall under PAM Generic, disabled by default in Fail2ban, so don't forget to enable it in jail.conf

Comment: @matega ,So fail2ban is the same as iptables with ipsets?

Comment: Take a look at its [wiki page](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). `Generally Fail2Ban is then used to update firewall rules`(=iptables with ipsets)`to reject the IP addresses for a specified amount of time...` But you will have to write code to interface your webapp with fail2ban anyway, so I would leave fail2ban out of it altogether if I were you. Also, iptables+ipsets is about as lightweight as you can get.